# Correct way to integrate jQuery plugins in AngularJS

Tags: jquery-plugins, angularjs

I was wondering what is the correct way to integrate jQuery plugins into my angular app. I've found several tutorials and screen-casts but they seem catered to a specific plugin.

For Example:
http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs

Should I create a directive like so -

```
App.directive('directiveName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).'pluginActivationFunction'(scope.$eval(attrs.directiveName));
        }
    };
});
```

And then in the html call the script and the directive?

```
<div directiveName ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pluginName.js"></script>
```

Thanks ahead

Comment: yes, the best approach is to wrap the required jQuery plugin's inside a directive, so you get the benefit of scope variables & control the initialization / method invokation.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about eval in any circumstance...heard its just bad practice

Comment: It should be `$(element).pluginActivationFunction(scope.$eval(attrs.directiveName));` without the quotes.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If you are using a jQuery plugin, do not put the code in the controller. Instead create a directive and put the code that you would normally have inside the `link` function of the directive.

There are a couple of points in the documentation that you could take a look at. You can find them here:
[Common Pitfalls](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#common-pitfalls)

[Using controllers correctly](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#using-controllers-correctly)

Ensure that when you are referencing the script in your view, you refer it last - after the angularjs library, controllers, services and filters are referenced.

EDIT: Rather than using `$(element)`, you can make use of `angular.element(element)` when using AngularJS with jQuery

Comment: How about jQuery plugins' parameters which allow HTML content? (for example if I want to add an `ng-click` directive through this plain text HTML parameter)

Comment: @Fractaliste Not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: can you explain what exactly does all $(element).'pluginActivationFunction'(scope.$eval(attrs.directiveName)); means ?

Comment: I am almost a total newbie of angularjs. I tried to use several jquery plugins and none of them worked. Do we really need to do this ? Can't they just work along angularjs ? It sound so boilerplate to me.

Comment: Why does the script need to come last ?

Comment: @MikeR That's cause there is a possibility that the scripts that arrive later may override the behaviour required by your plugin. To make sure that the plugin behaviour is still intact, you put it last.

Comment: Is there any advantage to use angular.element(element) over $(element)?

Comment: @LVarayut None. `angular.element` is an alias to `jQuery`. Since angularjs also as a convention of using `$` (example, `$scope`), you can use `angular.element` to avoid confusion

Comment: You didn't explain WHY do we need link function instead of a controller. Your links don't have this information too.

Answer (score 0):

i have alreay 2 situations where directives and services/factories didnt play well.

the scenario is that i have (had) a directive that has dependency injection of a service, and from the directive i ask the service to make an ajax call (with $http).

in the end, in both cases the ng-Repeat did not file at all, even when i gave the array an initial value.

i even tried to make a directive with a controller and an isolated-scope

only when i moved everything to a controller and it worked like magic.

example about this here [Initialising jQuery plugin (RoyalSlider) in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934698/initialising-jquery-plugin-royalslider-in-angular-js/32498228#32498228)