# Calling Javascript within ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have some legacy jQuery code. It's a big chunk of code, so I would prefer to port it a little while later. To use it, I call `$('#legacyId').legacyFunction()`.

Here's the deal, though.

I have an ng-if. And within that ng-if, I have the JavaScript where I call my legacy function.

```
<div ng-if="status=='yes'">
    <div id="legacyId">
        I am a legacy div!
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#legacyId').legacyFunction()
    </script>
</div>
```

It looks like this JavaScript is being called when the page loads. Though I load angular after jQuery, it seems that angular removes the section under control of the ng-if, and therefore the jQuery function on `#legacyId` fails.

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

**Edit-note**: I import jQuery and the legacy code that extends jQuery at the top of my HTML document. Angular is loaded at the bottom of the document.

---

**Edit-note 2**: I have also tried `<div ng-init="$('#legacyId').legacyFunction()"></div>`, but I get an error, `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress.`

Comment: Is this a typo? <div ng-if="status=='yes' (missing ")?

Comment: Yes, but no typo in actual source. Fixed.

Comment: Perhaps something with `$scope.$watch` could do the trick... Looking into it.

Comment: trying to lay angular over top jQuery DOM manipulation code is bad idea. Generally should work other way around, use angular first, then if need some DOM manipulation using jQuery, wrap it in a directive and call the jQuery from directive

Comment: Thanks charlieftl. Do you have any good examples? I do see, for example [Combining AngularJS with existing Components](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html). A bit more work than I want to dive into this moment, but could be a great resource a week or two from now.

Comment: ... or perhaps something like this is sufficient [StackOverflow: Correct way to integrate Jquery plugins in Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js)

Comment: here's a primitive demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/OZwPsSP6PQPHhmXDB8ql?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

Okay, managed to work this out.

In the HTML:

```
<div ng-if="status=='yes'">
    <div legacy-directive>
        I am a legacy div!
    </div>
</div>
```

In my app code:

```
app.directive('legacyDirective' , function() {
   return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).legacyFunction(scope.$eval(attrs.legacyDirective));
        }
   }
});
```

Because of the `$(element).legacyFunction(scope.$eval(attrs.legacyDirective));`, it looks like I can also pass parameters to the `legacyFunction`; e.g. `<div legacy-directive='{myParameter: true}>`

Thank you for all who answered! You set me on the right track.

Comment: if jQuery included in page before angular library, `element` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap in `$()`