# ng-if isn't preventing custom directive from initializing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-if` which I know should evaluate to false.. but noticing my directive `posSlider` is still being initialized via it's function `initValues()`

**page.html**

```
<div ng-if="bigdata.pieces[index].type == 'pos'" class="control-lock pos-detail-container" >
  ...
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class=" vVertical " ng-model="posValue" pos-slider ng-class="{'vclosed':bigdata.pieces[index].state.meta=='open'}"/>
 </div>
```

Can someone explain what's going on?  I thought the ng-if would prevent the directive from initializing until true

**directive.js**

```
orion.directive('posSlider', function($ionicGesture, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $timeout) {
"use strict";

return {
    restrict :  'A',
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs, e) {
        function initValues() {

            if (scope.detail.state.meta === 'open') {
                scope.posValue = 0;
            }

            else if (scope.detail.state.meta === 'closed') {
                scope.posValue = 100;
            }
        }

        initValues();
   ...
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824121/calling-javascript-within-ng-if

Comment: @Erick thank you but this doesn't get at my problem of understanding how angularJS runtime works..

Comment: What do you mean by "initialized"? ngIf is evaluated in its link() function, so if you've got some code in your directive further up the chain, or if your directive is running at a higher priority, then I'd expect it to be executed.

Comment: it is very difficult to understand what is going on here with so little code, as I do not see what `bigdata.peices` is, along with how you are tracking your `ng-repeat` (which I am assuming you are using), but as a guess, did you mean `$index` instead of `index`?

Comment: @c0bra added some details for you.  when i say initialized, I mean I'm seeing the `posSlider` function getting called.  I didn't expect that since it was nested in the `ng-if`

Comment: @WebWanderer `bigdata` is merely an object in the global namespace (i didnt write this, bare with me), with `pieces` being an array.  `index` is `index`.. no dollar sign.

Comment: I would debug by checking the actual value of bigdata.pieces. I tried your use case in a plunker and the it's working like you'd want it to: http://plnkr.co/edit/H3W1bAUtVypSpDf9aLys?p=preview

Comment: @Erik, that *is* how `ng-if` should work - check with `ng-if="false"`.