# How to call a directive function from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a simple loading directive, that I can use over and over, but I don't seem to get it working. I have the following code.

```js
var river = angular.module('river', []);

river.directive('riverLoading', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="text-center" style="padding-bottom: 20px;" ng-show="loading">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh fa-spin" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> {{ message }} {{ loading }}' +
    '</div>',
    scope: {
      acessor: '=',
      message: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.loading = true;
      
      $scope.finished = function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
      };
    }
  }
});

river.controller('ClientController', function($scope) {
  // This is in an $http.finished.
  // $scope.loadingClients.finished(); // This does not work (why?)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="river" ng-controller="ClientController">

<river-loading acessor="loadingClients" message="Loading clients.."></river-loading>
  
</div>
```

How can I get this to work and what am I doing wrong? I see other examples that are doing the same thing and they work. But they usually don't have an isolated scope and just call $scope.finished();.

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478194/angularjs-trigger-directive-from-controller-call

Comment: As it is, you only have to control the `$scope.loadingClients` flag from the controller.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't really want to use a service if I don't need to if there is an other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange what you are doing, as you could just use the two-way binding.  However, I think your problem is that you need your `finished` function to be:

```
$scope.acessor.finished = function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
};
```

i.e. you want to bind a `finished` function on the reference that you've passed in.  However, it would be much simpler to just have your template in your directive to look like this:

```
template: '<div class="text-center" style="padding-bottom: 20px;" ng-show="loading.show">' +
'<i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh fa-spin" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> {{ message }} {{ loading }}' +
'</div>',
```

Remove your controller from the directive, and your `ClientController` becomes:

```
river.controller('ClientController', function($scope) {
  $scope.loading = {show: true}
  // This is in an $http.finished.
  // $scope.loadingClients.finished(); // This does not work (why?)
  $scope.loading.show = false
});
```

That way you can just use the 2-way data binding.

I would also read up on using a dot ('.') in your scopes as otherwise you'll end up with the Javascript object shadowing problem.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482).