# Unable to load images for RoyalSlider in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

An angular app loads images after a user action like so:

```
<div class="royalSlider rsDefault" royalSlider>
  <img class="rsImg" ng-repeat="i in selectedAsset[0].images" ng-src="{{ i }}" />
</div>
```

In trying to use the [RoyalSlider Jquery plugin](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/), I used a directive:

```
app.directive('royalSlider', function() {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('selectedAsset', function(){
            element.royalSlider({
                keyboardNavEnabled: true,
                autoScaleSlider: true,
                autoHeight: true
            });
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: linker
    }
});
```

The problem is that the above deletes the images from the DOM when royalslider is instantiated.

What am I missing?

Comment: when you debug, is `element.royalSlider()` being called before `selectedAsset` actually has a value?

Comment: @greener can we have a fiddle on this??

Comment: for any1 with some ajax, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934698/initialising-jquery-plugin-royalslider-in-angular-js/32498228#32498228

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the directive right in your view. Use it like this:

```
<div class="royalSlider rsDefault" royal-slider>
  <img class="rsImg" ng-repeat="i in selectedAsset[0].images" ng-src="{{ i }}" />
</div>
```