# Javascript Framework compatible with JQuery Plugin

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework

I have to integrate an existing UI application to a REST based back end. The UI is a single html page that uses JQuery + CSS to create a sliding tab experience. Both the UI and REST application are Spring Boot apps.

I'm new to Javascript frameworks. AngularJS made a lot of sense to me for data binding and updating the DOM.

However, now that I am trying to do the integration, there is a .js include in the UI that contains a massive set of JQuery plugins (they are just pasted in one after another).

AngularJS functionality like 'ng-repeat' does not work with this file included. The UI application does not work without this include.

I believe the solution is to put all JQuery Plugins into a Angular Directive ([Initialising jQuery plugin (RoyalSlider) in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934698/initialising-jquery-plugin-royalslider-in-angular-js)). This looks like a painful task.

Are there other frameworks that would work with this?

I have found some threads suggesting a ground up approach with Angular (["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)), but I'm stuck with this current UI app's structure.

Suggestions? I'm thinking of using JQuery to acquire the JSON and inject it into the UI and adding Thymeleaf for its fragments.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have found that using JQuery is the way to go if your application was built with JQuery. If I could do it again, perhaps Angular should have been the base for the UI application. However,after some exploration, I have found JQuery does a lot of cool things around AJAX and Dom manipulation. When used with ThymeLeaf in Spring Boot, you end up with a power set of UI tools.