# AngularJS with jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to use the [jQuery scollsnap plugin](http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/) in AngularJS, and have tried following the guide from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js). However, it neither gives an error nor does it work.

This is what I had.

```
App.directive('scrollsnap', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(element).scrollsnap({ snaps: 'section' });
        }
    };
});
```

And in my HTML:

```
<body scrollsnap class="... ... ...>
```

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: @runTarm: As mentioned, "it neither gives an error nor does it work". No error given.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that. BTW, there is no need to wrap the `element` with `angular.element()`, it is already wrapped.

Comment: Has the link function really been called? May be put a `console.log()` in there and see if it output something.

Comment: @runTarm No worries :) The link function has been called and returns the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery plugin may need to be initialized after the view has been rendered.

Try using $timeout:

```
App.directive('scrollsnap', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
               angular.element(element).scrollsnap({ snaps: 'section' });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hmm, is this the best-practice? Using timeouts to wait for the view to render?

Comment: Yes.. if you're mixing jquery plugins with angular.  There is no _after_ _render_ event in angular that you can hook into, but often times you need one when initializing jquery plugins.  $timeout accomplishes this. The angular way might be to not use jquery plugins.

Comment: Here is a feature request for the Angular team to introduce an _after_ _render_ event: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734. In the discussion, they suggest best practice is not use code (jquery plugins) that necessitates the need for an after render process. Compilation is a continuous process, so to discourage the (bad) practice of hooking in code that runs after the render event, they don't make it easy or intuitive.  $timeout waits until after the render phase has finished before executing the code - not by design, its just how it works.

Comment: Before reaching for your jquery toolbox, check if there is an angular way to do the same thing using directives. You might be able to do the same thing with a fraction of the code. If you still can't find a way, check with the community, maybe they have ideas. If you still can't find a way, ask google, or look through some Angular textbooks.  Basically, only reach for your jquery toolbox as a last resort. And since it is a last resort, might as well use $timeout to initialize your plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I don't seem to find any plugins for AngularJS that snaps the scroll to elements. I'll probably have to go with this and will give it a try.