# Jquery plugin not working inside AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use a Jquery plugin (Star Rating plugin - [link](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating/demo)) inside AngularJS's ng-repeat directive but I dont know why its not working. If I try out outside Angular's scope then its doing its job flawlessly.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="datum in data">
        <span>Name : {{datum.name}}</span><br/>
        <span>Age : {{datum.age}}</span><br/>
        <input id="rater" class="rating" value={{datum.rate}} min=0 max=5 step=1><!--Third party rating plugin-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The html input which get parsed as a Star rating with value fetched from backend via ajax request. I guess the culprit seems to be the timing, Jquery completes its task before Angular does, so is there any other way to accomplish this one? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create a directive for this jquery plugin (or search if it exists already)

Comment: There should be a different id for each input tag the ng-repeat creates. You could create an extra directive for the StarRating plugin. In the directive you can directly access the JQuery element withour usind an id.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom directive and linked my attributes. Now it works awesome. Please find the code snippet below.

My directive:

```
renapp.directive('srater',function(){
 return {
 restrict : 'AE',
 link : function(scope, elem, attr){
   $(elem).rating('update', attr.value);
  }
 } 
});
```

Html :

```
<srater value={{datum.rate}} data-show-clear="false" readonly="true"></srater>
```

Thanks Guys for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap and look for rating directive, Its an AngularJS `<rating>` directive.

Angular Tip: Always search for angular js directive before falling back to jQuery plugins

Comment: Thanks Siraj - I've used directive. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for this might be using `jquery setimeout()` function after window load.

It might not be good approach but it is easient one for me and works fine.

Code look something like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {        
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#rater").rating();
    }, 10); /****10 is dealy in milliseconds**/
});
```

And If you are using http service then you can also use angularjs $timeout Service

Something like that

```
   $scope.show_ratings = function(id) {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : SITE_URL+"angular_http/fetch_ratings.php",
            params: {subcateid: id}
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.fetch_ratings = response.data.records;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myerror = response.statusText;
        });
        $timeout(function () {
            jQuery("#rater").rating();
        }, 500);
    },
```

I hope it will work well for all.