# How can i use jquery plugins for my AngularJS Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, single-page-application

The CSS works fine always.
but the jquery code (jquery plugins or custom jquery code) does not work in the ng-view (partials)

its not about few jquery functions for which i can always rewrite jquery code using angular directives. here the major problem is, i am using a lot of jquery plugins, so the whole code contains hundreds of jquery functions, effects, transitions. so i want a practical way to make all this work inside angular ng-view using partials with minimum labor.

what changes are necessary to make such jquery code/plugins work with angular?
what is the best solution?

ps:
is backbone.js better in this respect? is it easier to use jquery plugins with backbone or same problem there also?

Comment: jQuery is primarily a DOM library and you're not supposed to mess with the DOM in Angular

Comment: Can probably get rid of most of them and convert to angular methodology. Run the others inside directives

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/

and

[Correct way to integrate jQuery plugins in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js)