# AngularJS loading javascript in partials

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a partial in my AngularJS application that needs a 3rd party .js file to run. In order for this partial to work correctly, I have to have the javascript load after the page is loaded in the app view.

What I have so far is this for the directive to include the scripts:

```
.directive('loadScripts',function() {
  return {
    restrict :'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element('<script src="/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>').append(element);
    }
  }
})
```

Then on the partial I have `<div load-scripts></div>`. The partial doesn't get anything loaded, the directive isn't adding the html tags to the page. Any ideas on what I should do?

I reviewed a similar question/answer here: [Correct way to integrate Jquery plugins in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js)

I appear to be following it exactly, except i'm using angular.element instead. I'm tried different tests and none of the element is being included into the DOM

Comment: That is wrong. you are doing the otherway around. However you need to created script element and append it to `element`. Not sure why are you doing this. You could just put the script in the view itself. You could just do `['/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', '/js/main.js'].forEach(function(url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        element.append(script);
      });`

Comment: You actually create the script tag, that is ok but afterwards, you append the existing directive element on it. Nothing there can happen. You can try: `element.replaceWith(angular.element('<script src="/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'));`

Comment: @HimmetAvsar i believe that is a wrong way to do.