# $ and comma should allow on text box but should not save them

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have below mentioned requirement.
On the text box need to allow any characters like `"$"` and , but while saving need to strip them and save only numbers and a `"."`

**eg:** if user enters $14,500.50 save 14500.50

do not show an error in case `"$"` or `","` is entered.

How can I do that ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note : At this moment text box is only allowed numeric characters.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us your code.

Comment: @doldt No idea how to do that.At this moment I do have numeric text box.

Comment: Right-click, view source. Post server receiving method too

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean by 'server receiving method'.This is just a numeric text box at the moment where bind to the model property ?

Comment: You tagged this JavaScript and C# so with your lack of further description I assumed JavaScript was used to validate and C# used to store it. So we need the validation method/regex used to block the $ and comma and the C# method to see how you currently parse the value received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var newString=yourstring.replace(/[$,]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just parse the number including culture info and numberstyles

```
string number = "$14,500.50";
double d;
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
if(Double.TryParse(number,
                   NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol,
                   c,
                   out d))
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Output: 14500.5

[IDEOne example](https://ideone.com/WEWM1Q)

[Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of Plugins mastering this. https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask. 
You need to mask your input so that you can access the masked input value and the raw decimal value.

Comment: I need an Angular solution.Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in field masks. There is [angular-input-masks](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) that should allow you to do it. See the [ui-money-mask](http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/) from demo.

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple actually, you just need to add that replace function in the $parsers pipeline . $parsers do the needed transformation and validation when any value goes from view to model .

Suppose this is your input tag:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<input type="text" ng-model="currency">
</body>
```

Now, in the app.js file :

```
var app=angular.module('app',[])
app.directive('input',function(){
return {
    restrict:'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elm,attr,ngModelCtrl){
        function convert(input){
            input = input.replace(/\$/g,'');
             input = input.replace(/,/g,'');
             return input;
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(convert);
    }
}
})
```

Here, you are modifying the input directive to replace $ and , with '' (done in the convert function). The convert function is pushed to the $parsers pipeline which will strip off any $ and from any  number in the input directive , and store the stripped off number in the model .

Here is a plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ViqqDWex3NSz9ZtTc7DZ?p=preview)

You can see the model value "currency" not containing the $ and , sign

Comment: If you are not much familiar with $parsers and ngModelCtrl , then do have a look at this blogpost [link](http://mean-aakash.blogspot.in/2015/02/pipeline-of-ngmodelcontroller.html)

Comment: Can you tell me how to filter other characters (except $ ,comma and dot (.) ) ? In other words only allow numeric and above 3 character types ?

Comment: Yaa you can do that too , by adding the functions to allow minimum three characters , which should only be numeric in the $parsers pipeline . I have modified the previous plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ViqqDWex3NSz9ZtTc7DZ?p=preview) to allow this. In , the plunker , min3numbers function allows only minimum three characters that too numeric characters , only then the value will be saved in the model . (value of the model is inside <pre> tag)