# How to inform AngularJS of change made by a Jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery timepicker for bootstrap. With the help of Angular UI-Utils jQuery passthrough, I was able to make the clockface show up.

```
<input type="text" ui-jq="clockface"
       ng-model="data.Event.time_end" data-format="hh:mm A" />
```

However, the value of the ng-model doesn't change if you use the clockface. How do I inform AngularJS of the changes that this plugin is doing?

Comment: This could be what your looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js

Comment: Check the link you gave, I actually tried that option too.. same thing the ng-model doesn't get update with the change in value via the jquery plugin  (clockface)

Comment: but if i edit the input text, ng-model gets updated as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell angular regarding changes made by jQuery by calling `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: i'm listening to the change event of the input box, but it seems clockface is not triggering that event.. element.bind('change', function() {...

Comment: @Jasper Did you added this in your directive?

Comment: yes. based from answer below by nsmarks, i listened to the pick.clockface event triggered by clockface and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to this plugin: http://vitalets.github.io/clockface/

Setup an event handler for `pick.clockface` as detailed on the website. See this line of code in the plugin for more details: https://github.com/vitalets/clockface/blob/6f2ec125d42c9a9172e54c81625b452c5f96a682/js/clockface.js#L318

> All events have second parameter data with current `hour`, `minute` and `ampm` values.

Comment: Hey Jasper, great! I think you selected the wrong answer though. Can you update this as the correct answer for future viewers?