# How to use jQuery Plugins when using Angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

I've been trying to figure out how could i use a jQuery plugin when using Angular.js, right now i'm using **Angular 1.4**, some questions i have are:

- Can i use the jQuery version that comes with Angular when using plugins?
- When do i need to use another version of jQuery when using Angular?
- Are there any consequences when using a different version of jQuery?
- How do i know what's the latest supported jQuery version Angular supports?
- When referencing the libraries in the html which i load first, Angular or jQuery?

What i have found so far are these examples/tutorials:

- [An approach to use jQuery plugins with Angular](https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/)
- [Angular Other jQuery Plugin Demo](https://github.com/gaurav123337/AngularOtherJqueryPluginDemo/tree/master/js)
- [Correct way to integrate jQuery plugins in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs)

But what i don't get is how to tell from angular the jquery properties, here's what i mean:

Let's say i want to use [onepage-scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) plugin, when using just jquery code is like this:

### Standard JQuery Way

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <section class="page1">
        <div class="page_container">
            <h1>One Page Scroll</h1>

            <h2>Create an Apple-like one page scroller website (iPhone 5S website) with One Page Scroll plugin</h2>

            <div class="btns"><a class="reload btn" href="https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll">Download on
                Github</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="phones.png" alt="phones">
    </section>
    <section class="page2">
        <div class="page_container">
            <h1>Ready-to-use plugin</h1>

            <h2>All you need is an HTML markup, call the script and BAM!</h2>

            <div class="btns"><a class="reload btn" href="https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll">Download on
                Github</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".main" ).onepage_scroll( {//These are the properties i talk about
        sectionContainer: "section",
        responsiveFallback: 600,
        loop: true
    } )
});
```

What would be the angular way to transform that jquery code into a ng-directive?

Here's what i understand i have to do:

### Angular Way

**JS:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.layout' )
        .directive( 'jqOnepageScroll', jqOnepageScroll );

    function jqOnepageScroll() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

                $( element ).onepage_scroll( scope.$eval( attrs.jqOnepageScroll ) );

            }
        };
    }

})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main"
     jq-onepage-scroll="{
             sectionContainer: 'section', 
             responsiveFallback: 600, 
             loop: true
         }">
    <section class="page1">
        ...
    </section>
    <section class="page2">
        ...
    </section>
</div>
```

But what i don't understand is what happened with this: `$( ".main" ).onepage_scroll` ? I understand that in angular it is this: `$( element ).onepage_scroll` but that piece of code says explicit *element*, how do i tell the class `main` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your directive approach is close on target however it is missing function argument.

Also the `element` argument of link function will already be a jQuery object so no need to wrap it in `$()` again.

There is no need to specify the element class when you already have the element object available

```
angular
    .module( 'app.layout' )
    .directive( 'jqOnepageScroll', jqOnepageScroll );//forgot function arg

function jqOnepageScroll() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            // unwrap $(element)
            element.onepage_scroll( scope.$eval( attrs.jqOnepageScroll ) );

        }
    };
}
```

As far as the jQuery version, angular doesn't include jQuery so it is whatever version you include ***before*** angular.js script tag that gets used. See [angular.element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)