# jquery $('div').html not working with third party modules (Angular)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am having trying to show content of a `<div id="right">` when a mouse is hovered on another div. `#right` contains a graph from Angular-charts (http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).

Here is my jQuery:

```
                    <div>
                       <div>
                          <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" click="onClick">
                          </canvas>
                       </div>
                       <h3>Some text</h3>
                    </div>
```

I tried implementing this to show in #right when hovered over my other div in my jQuery.

```
 $(function(){

          $('#some_other_div').on('mouseover', function(){
            $('#right').html('<div><canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" click="onClick"></canvas></div><h3>Some text</h3>');
            })     
    });
```

When hovering on `some_other_div`, Only a blank space and `Some text` shows at the bottom. I made sure the graph works elsewhere when implementing it directly in HTML. Only facing this problem through .html.

Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're using angular then you should check some things that doesn't play well with it, like using jquery in the bad way, you should use it the angular way

Comment: @NonExistent ill give it a try. Thank you

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682145/how-to-use-jquery-plugins-when-using-angular-js) (Don't care about the -1, read the content) i posted some links to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the html outside the Angular system doesn't tell Angular that the DOM is changed for it to act. Try doing the change via $apply() function.

```
angular.element("#some_other_div").scope().$apply($('#right').html('<div><canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" click="onClick"></canvas></div><h3>Some text</h3>');)
```