# jQuery thumbnail grid in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I'm attempting to use a thumbnail grid in my AngularJS application. I've set up a directive for the HTML template part, but am having trouble initializing the jQuery part that expands a tile on click.

I know this is a typical issue when attempting to use jQuery in Angular apps. The jQuery script is very simple, I just don't know how to make it work in Angular. The script:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            Grid.init();
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks for any advice/help!

**Edit:**
Page is here: [tinyurl.com/jgbrpd6](http://tinyurl.com/jgbrpd6). As you can see, if you click on one of the elements, nothing happens because the jQuery script is located in the HTML of the templateUrl file.

templateUrl file is here: [tinyurl.com/zr9ylqf](http://tinyurl.com/zr9ylqf). As you can see, if you click on one of the elements, it behaves as expected, becuase it is now outside of the AngularJS app.

Comment: This information isn't information.. Have you copied same code? Do you see any console errors?

Comment: There are no console errors. To make the plugin work in jQuery, the only script needed is the one I've posted + dependencies, which load fine.

Comment: Did you paste the `javascript` given in the link into a file and included it?

Comment: Does not do anything different than including it in a script tag. Just FYI about using jQuery in Angular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs

Comment: Angular does not need `jQuery` as of my knowledge, but am not sure whether you have included your code or not.. Can you create a **[`DEMO HERE`](http://jsfiddle.net)**