# ng-Directive getting called before ng-Controller to bind the data to HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first post in Stack and I'm new to Angular. I'm working on generating dynamic span tags instead of putting them in HTML. It works fine when I've static HTML code, but it doesn't work when its being called from Angular. Because ng-Directive is getting called before ng-Controller.

Here is the static HTML code

```
<scroller height="150" width="200" padding="5" ng-model="test">

<span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a><p class="title">img0</p></span>
<span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a><p class="title">img1</p></span>
<span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a><p class="title">img2</p></span>
</scroller>
```

What I'm trying to do is in the following fashion.

```
<scroller height="150" width="200" padding="5" ng-model="test">
    <div ng-repeat="image in imagesArray">

        <span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img ng-src='{{image.img}}'/></a><p class="imgtitle">{{image.title}}</p></span>

      </div>
      </scroller>
```

My Controller code

```
function myCtrl($scope,$http){
 $scope.test = 0;  
 $http.get("data.json")
  .then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    $scope.imagesArray = response.data.imagesArray || [];
    console.log($scope.imagesArray);
  });
```

}

Objects would be getting created in the following way.

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
img: "images/img1.png"
title: "img1 "
```

etc ..

Do I need to follow anything else? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can You please add your angular js controller code.

Comment: @Rahul, updated with Controller code. Please check it.

Comment: I suspect your scroller directive is using an isolate scope.
  Can you provide your code for the scroller directive

Answer (score 1):

> You need to repeat `span` elements. Current code will repeat `div` elements which will create multiple `block` level elements which is not the expected output.
>
> `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection

Try this:

```html
<scroller height="150" width="200" padding="5" ng-model="test">
  <span ng-repeat="image in imagesArray"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img ng-src='{{image.img}}'/></a><p class="imgtitle">{{image.title}}</p></span>
</scroller>
```

Comment: the above snippet is building in the following format <span ng-repeat="image in imagesArray" class="ng-scope"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img ng-src="images/img1.png" src="images/img1.png"></a><p class="imgtitle ng-binding">img1 </p></span> for all span tags

Comment: That is how your static html is...Right ?

Comment: I've put the static HTML code in the question itself. That's correct static HTMl

Comment: I understood it why.. My directive is getting called initially and then the controller. that's why its not getting binded. How can I bind the data initially itself in the directive call?

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs