# how to create an angular directive to load jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to use jSignature jquery plugin with my mvc+angular js project,but i am unable to load the jquery in the project since i dont have a proper directive to load it,help is needed.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.signature.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#sig').signature();
        $('#clear').click(function () {
            $('#sig').signature('clear');
        });
        $('#json').click(function () {
            alert($('#sig').signature('toJSON'));
        });
        $('#svg').click(function () {
            alert($('#sig').signature('toSVG'));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

this is the code i used alongside the jquery plugin,but a directive is required to properly load the jquery,some help is needed to write the directive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to integrate jQuery plugins in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a directive to *load* jQuery. Just include jQuery before including AngularJS, angular will use jQuery instead of jQlite.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to include third party js code is to create a directive that wraps code in the `link` function:

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    link:link
  };

  function link($scope, $element, $attr){

      (function ($) {
        $('#sig').signature();
        $('#clear').click(function () {
            $('#sig').signature('clear');
        });
        $('#json').click(function () {
            alert($('#sig').signature('toJSON'));
        });
        $('#svg').click(function () {
            alert($('#sig').signature('toSVG'));
        });
      }(jQuery));
  });

});
```

And finally include the directive where needed.