# how to work with jquery plugins into angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can i use the jQuery image slider  plugins that comes with Angular ?
 what is the correct way to integrate jQuery plugins slider into my angular.
give  solution for jquery  pluings .

Comment: As far as I know, there are no jQuery sliders that “come with angular”.

Comment: What is that u have tried in code?? Update them! Before asking help suggest you to have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs