# Angularjs Slider working only in Index.html

Tags: html, angularjs

I try to use my html template in angularjs project but when I try to move the slider from Index.html to other html file is not working is show like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT2Ze.jpg)

and this is the original

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y1x3.png)

all other part of page is working fine when move it to other file only the slider

this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>*</title>
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/revolution-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/masterslider/style/masterslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/masterslider/skins/default/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/masterslider/style/ms-vertical.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Responsive -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>


<body>

<div class="page-wrapper">

    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- Main Header / header-style-two-->
    <header class="main-header header-style-two">
        <!-- Header Top -->

        <!-- Header Top End -->





    </header>
    <!--End Main Header -->


     <div ng-view></div>


    <!--Main Footer-->


</div>
<!--End pagewrapper-->

<!--Scroll to top-->
<div class="scroll-to-top scroll-to-target" data-target="html"><span class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

<script src="js/revolution.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-css/angular-css.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/app.js"></script> 
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','angularCSS','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate','ngTouch']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            controller: "HomeCtrl",
            templateUrl: "home.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

home.html

```
<section class="main-slider" data-start-height="950" data-slide-overlay="yes">

        <div class="tp-banner-container">
            <div class="tp-banner">
                <ul>

                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/s1.jpeg"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Awesome Title Here">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/s1.jpeg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption sfb sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="-90"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><figure class="content-image"><img src="images/main-slider/icon-1.png" alt=""></figure></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfl sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="30"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><h2>The Delicous Food Tasts</h2></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfr sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="120"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><div class="text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.Sed<br>ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium </div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfl sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="200"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><a href="#" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">Buy Now</a></div>

                    </li>

                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/s2.jpg"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Awesome Title Here">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/s2.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption sfb sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="-90"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><figure class="content-image"><img src="images/main-slider/icon-1.png" alt=""></figure></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfl sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="30"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><h2>The Delicous Food Tasts</h2></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfr sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="120"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><div class="text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.Sed<br>ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium </div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfl sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="200"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><a href="#" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">Buy Now</a></div>

                    </li>

                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/main-slider/s3.jpg"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Awesome Title Here">
                    <img src="images/main-slider/s3.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"> 

                    <div class="tp-caption sfb sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="left" data-hoffset="30"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="-90"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><figure class="content-image"><img src="images/main-slider/icon-2.png" alt=""></figure></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfl sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="left" data-hoffset="30"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="30"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><h2>The Fresh And Tasty Burgers</h2></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfr sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="left" data-hoffset="30"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="120"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><div class="text text-left">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque <br>aperiam.Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit </div></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfl sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="left" data-hoffset="30"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="200"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><a href="#" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">Buy Now</a></div>

                    <div class="tp-caption sfb sfb tp-resizeme"
                    data-x="right" data-hoffset="0"
                    data-y="center" data-voffset="-40"
                    data-speed="1500"
                    data-start="500"
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"
                    data-splitin="none"
                    data-splitout="none"
                    data-elementdelay="0.01"
                    data-endelementdelay="0.3"
                    data-endspeed="1200"
                    data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"><figure class="content-image"><img src="images/main-slider/content-image.png" alt=""></figure></div>

                    </li>

                </ul>

                <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: The slider in writed in Angular or JQuery?

Comment: @FabioPicheli I use slider revolution with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a `jQuery` plugin for a Angular application you have a common error: when the JS is executed the HTML template is not loaded.

Probably that's why you are having this issue, when you put the code in the index file, the HTML is already loaded when when the JS is executed, but when you put in a template, the JS is executed, don't find any element and then the element "appers".

A good solution is put all the `jQuery` code in a directive and use the `direct`. You can take a look in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs).

But for your case, sameone already did what I just said, and you can use the "migrated" code, take a look in the [angular-revolution](https://github.com/Karnith/angular-revolution) lib..