# How to write jquery code in Angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hi I am  developing Website in angularjs and i am doing Registration page.I am trying to implement validation(Jquery plugin). I have imported required css and js files. 
Below is my html code.

```
 <input class="form-control validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="{{ 'Last Name' | translate }}" ng-model="Lname">
```

Below is my Registration controller.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('MainRegistration', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', 'cfg', function ($rootScope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, cfg) {

        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('Registration');
        $translate.refresh();
        $translate.use('de_AR');
    }]);
})();
```

To implement validation i want to write below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
            $("formID").attr('autocomplete', 'off');

        });
    </script>
```

May I get some help where to write jquery code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angularjs

Comment: `angular.element()` is the answer. But why you need use it? >`I am trying to implement validation(Jquery plugin)`. angular boostrap helps to implement validation. then why you go to jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.element()` is the correct way to select the elements in angularjs.

But you can simply write the while code in your controller.

So just put the whole code from `$(document).ready()` to your controller and it will work.

And as far as the form validation is concerned, you can use **Angularjs Form Validation**.

You can refer 
**Angular Form Properties $valid, $invalid, $pristine, $dirty** at the link below.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 1):

You can write your jquery code like this in angularjs

```
// binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    angular.element(document.getElementById("formID")).validationEngine();
    angular.element(document.getElementById("formID")).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

But that's really wrong way to implement validations, as angular have built in features to handle validations. please refer this link 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms