# AngularJS - Jquery-TreeTable how to dynamically add columns in the tree-table when these columns' data based on an api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, treetable

My [jquery-tree-table](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/) has some fixed columns and dynamic columns, these dynamic columns are based on the data returned from an api.

The api gives me an array[n], then it will show n colums.

But now I have problem even in show rows, it does not show as tree in tree-table.

Could you tell me where is the problem?

JS:

```
$scope.load = function(){
            var treeTableOptions = {
                expandable:true,
            };
            
            myService.selectDataOfTree({
                
            }).then(function (responses) {
               if(responses){
                   var data = responses;
                   $scope.data = data;
               }
               $("#example-basic").treetable(treeTableOptions);
            });
            
        }
```

`$scope.data` is something like:

```
[
  {
    assetId: 1, 
    assetparentID: 0, 
    name:"xx",
    address:"xx",
    info:[{},{}]
  },
  {
    assetId: 2, 
    assetparentID: 1,
    name:"xx",
    address:"xx", 
    info:[{},{}]
  }
]
```

my-customer.html:

```
 <table id="example-basic">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Column1</th>
           <th>Column2</th>
           <th>columns from info dynamically</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-tt-id="{{item.assetId}}" data-tt-parent-id="{{item.assetparentID}}" ng-repeat = "item in data">
            <td>
                    {{item.assetId}}
            </td>
            <td>
                    {{item.assetParentID}}
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat = "info in item.info">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

I try to use directives:

```
angular.module('custom.plug.tree.table', [])
.directive('customPlugTreeTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        scope:{
            initTreeTableOptionsFn :"&initTreeTableOptionsFn"
        },
       controller: function ($scope, $element, $q, wapPromptService) {
           this.treedata = $scope.initTreeTableOptionsFn();

        },
       templateUrl:'my-customer.html',
     
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, customObjectZtreeCtrl) {
            scope.data = customObjectZtreeCtrl.treedata;
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
<custom-plug-tree-table init-tree-table-options-fn="initTreeTableOptionsTest()">
</custom-plug-tree-table>
```

controller:

```
$scope.initTreeTableOptionsTest = function(){
            var treeTableOptions = {
                expandable:true,
            };
           
            $("#example-basic").treetable(treeTableOptions);
            var testData = [
                {
                  assetId: 42581, 
                  assetparentID: 362, 
                  info:[{},{}]
                },
                {
                  assetId: 42581, 
                  assetparentID: 243,
                  info:[{},{}]
                },
                {
                  assetId: 362, 
                  assetparentID: 0,
                  info:[{},{}]
                },
                {
                  assetId: 243, 
                  assetparentID: 362,
                  info:[{},{}]
                },
          
              ];
             
              getChildren(testData,0);

              return $scope.data;
        }
 function getChildren(data, id) {
            for (var i in data) {
                if (data[i].assetparentID == id) {
                    $scope.data.push(data[i]);
                    getChildren(data,data[i].assetId)
                }
                
            }
        }
```

But it still has the same problem...

[image]

Comment: It's likley that the ng-repeat creating the elements hasn't completed before the jQuery plugin has initialised. Best practise is to use AngularJS directives for this type of functionality. This touches on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16935288/1663821

Comment: @Michael I agree with you since it works when I manually write html code

Comment: @Michael,I use directive it still shows the content without tree style...